# UITexFiled always clear when I hit return

Tags: objective-c

I add a UITexfield programatically on my view. When I use keyboard and hit return button texfield cleared automatically and I don't want this.

Here is my code;

```
UITextField * eventListSeractTextField = [[UITextField   alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(headerView.frame.size.width-112,4, 110, 20)];
    eventListSeractTextField.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    eventListSeractTextField.layer.cornerRadius=3.0f;

    eventListSeractTextField.tag=101;
    eventListSeractTextField.delegate=self;
        eventListSeractTextField.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        eventListSeractTextField.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    eventListSeractTextField.spellCheckingType=UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
    eventListSeractTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    eventListSeractTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    eventListSeractTextField.placeholder=@"Search";
    eventListSeractTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing=false;
    [eventListSeractTextField setClearsOnBeginEditing:false];

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
switch (textField.tag) {

    case 101:
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return false;
        break;
    default:
       return YES;
}
return YES;
```

}

How can I avoid this?

Comment: is it get cleared or does it go to new line ? After you hit the return key, did u log the textfield text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are recreating the textview each time since you did it in code. Check where you are calling this line of code:

```
UITextField * eventListSeractTextField = [[UITextField   alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(headerView.frame.size.width-112,4, 110, 20)];
```

You should only need to create the textView once in viewDidLoad. The easier way would be to do it in storyboard if you are familiar with storyboard

Comment: Thank You. That is the answer.